# Real function such that restriction to any uncountable set is surjective

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

This is a problem posed by my professor, which I don't know how to prove (or find an example)

> Does there exist a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that the restriction of $f$ to any $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ with $|A| = \mathfrak{c}$  is surjective?

As I've said, I haven't made significant progress. An observation is that such a function is everywhere discontinuous but Darboux. I considered the Conway Base $13$ as a possible candidate, but I'm not sure if it takes on all real values when restricted to (for example) the Cantor set.

Comment: Assume it's true, consider $f^{-1}(0)$ and its complement.

Comment: hmmm... How many surjections  with  pairwise disjoint domain can you stuff into the real line?

Comment: @user251257 Is that just an idea or does it lead directly to a proof?

Comment: @Alephnull it does. It is pretty straight forward.

Comment: @user251257 Oh yes of course.

Comment: Maybe it's too late for me to be taking a leisure stroll on MSE. How do you arrive at a contradiction using the above hint?

Comment: @Martin $\mathbb R \setminus f^{-1}(0)$ can't be uncountable but maps subjectively into $\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: @user251257 That's perfect, you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume such function $f$ exists.

Let $A=\mathbb R \setminus f^{-1}(0)$. From $ f(A) = \mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$ follows that $A$ is not uncountable, but is mapped subjectively to a uncountable set. A contradiction.